# Do prophets sin? Genesis 27, Numbers 20, Jonah

Tags: prophecy, moses, sin, jacob

**Jacob**

Jacob is a prophet in both Christian and Jewish traditions. Among his prophetic activities were his dream of the ladder in Gen. 28:13 and the blessings he gave to his sons on his deathbed in Gen. 49, in which he predicted the future of their various tribes. Yet Jacob engaged in a serious act of deceit in obtaining his father's blessing, meant of Esau, in Gen. 27.

Jacob's act of deception may be justified on the grounds that God blessed him soon afterward with the above-mentioned dream in which the Lord promised that:

> The land on which you lie I will give to you and to your offspring,
> and your offspring shall be like the dust of the earth, and you shall
> spread abroad to the west and to the east and to the north and to the
> south, and all the families of the earth shall be blessed in you and
> in your offspring. Know that I am with you and will keep you wherever
> you go and will bring you back to this land, for I will not leave you
> until I have done what I have promised you. (28:13-15)

**Moses**

It may also be argued that Jacob's alleged sin in deceiving his father to take Esau's blessing was committed prior to his calling by God, so he was not yet a prophet. However, the case of Moses is more difficult. Moses, already the greatest of prophets, seems to have sinned in an important way when he struck the Rock in anger:

> Moses and Aaron gathered the assembly together before the rock, and he
> said to them, “Listen, you rebels; shall we bring water for you out of
> this rock?” Then Moses lifted up his hand and struck the rock twice
> with his staff; water came out abundantly, and the congregation and
> their livestock drank. But the Lord said to Moses and Aaron, “Because
> you did not trust in me, to show my holiness before the eyes of the
> Israelites, therefore you shall not bring this assembly into the land
> that I have given them. (Num. 20:10-17)

Moses was punished by God by not being allowed to enter the Promised Land, but he is honored by both Christianity and Judaism. In the latter he is the greatest prophet to have ever lived, and in Christianity, he is the model for Jesus, who himself was "a prophet like Moses." (Deuteronomy 18:15)

**Jonah**

Another case in point is that of Jonah, who tried to escape from God's command to preach at Nineveh because he feared the Ninevites would repent and be forgiven of their sins. He too was punished, but was given a second chance after spending three days in the belly of a great fish.

**Do prophets sin? Are the other cases where prophets seem to have acted either immorally or against God's will in any serious way?**

Comment: What is the point of this enquiry- all men have sinned, so what?

Comment: I started to formulate the question thinking about Jacob, whether his act of deception was a sin in God's sight, since God rewarded him immediately afterward. It evolved from there, wondering which prophets other than Moses might have sinned after God called them. I'm not aware of any of the classical prophets or even the minor prophets sinning.  Also I'm aware that in Islam prophets do not sin.

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad" - this question is about numerous passages, including many which are not specified, and is attempting more of a **systematic theology** of what a prophet is than exegesis of a specific passage or author. Denoting Jacob as a "prophet" for example, may not align with the authorial intent of the text. Did Moses or the Genesis author(s) consider Jacob a prophet, and did they intend to communicate him as sinning? There are far too many questions packed in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General Principle**

> Rom 3:10, 23 - “There is no one righteous, not even one. ... for all
> have sinned and fall short of the glory of God

Since prophets of God are human, there is no reason to exclude them from this general principle - they are human sinners like the rest of us, but, they have been chosen by God to receive or convey messages.  Here are some examples of prophets (who delivered messages from God) sinning. (This is far from an exhaustive list)

**Noah**

Noah preached at God's behest for 120 years and took instructions directly from God about the construction of the Ark.  However, he sinned greatly when he became naked and drunk (Gen 9).

**Abraham**

Abraham was prophet of God (Gen 12:1-3, 18:33, 20:7, 22:1, Acts 3:25, Luke 13:28, etc); however, Abraham lied about his wife twice, and stupidly got his maid (Hagar) pregnant.

**Isaac**

Isaac was a prophet on the basis of the beautify prophecies he uttered about his son Jacob (Gen 27) yet he also lied about his wife Rebekah (Gen 26)

**Jacob**

Jacob uttered some sublime prophecies about the future (Gen 49); yet he deceived his father (Gen 27)

**Moses**

Moses is still regarded as one of the greatest (if not the greatest) prophet among the Jews as he recorded the Torah, yet he was a murderer (Ex 2)

**Balaam**

Baalam also delivered some marvelous prophecies including messianic prophecies (seven in all, see Num 23, 24), yet he was greedy, took bribes and facilitated the seduction of Israel (Num 25, Ps 106:28, Num 31:16, Deut 4:3, etc)

**David**

King David wrote about half the psalms but committed some heinous acts with Bathsheba and Uriah (2 Sam 11, 12).

**Solomon**

Similarly, King Solomon, who wrote several OT books such as a few psalms (Ps 72, 127), Proverbs, Ecclesiastes, Song of Solomon, etc; yet he lost his way for many years, had many wives, built pagan temples installing graven images, and overtaxed Israel.

**Elijah**

The great prophet Elijah who caused to fire to come down from heaven (1 Kings 18) and was translated to heaven without seeing death, ran away from God, doubted God, and had to be rebuked (1 Kings 19).

**Jonah**

Jonah was a prophet called by God who ran away.

It is abundantly clear that the Bible prophets were human, sinners, needed to repent, needed God's salvation just as much any other human sinner.

Comment: I appreciate your going beyond the three prophets I mentioned.

Comment: Interesting that all of these are pre-classical prophets. I wonder if any of the 'literary prophets' admitted to sin.

Comment: @DanFefferman - the fact that no sin is recorded in the Bible does not at all preclude the fact of actual sin. " ... for all have sinned ..."

Comment: Of course. A related question is whether the sins committed by prophets or other providential figures has particular significance, as for example Moses striking the rock or Noah's drunkenness (if that was a sin). I suppose these questions are better asked on Ch.se than here?

Comment: @DanFefferman - we have the explicit statement of James 3:1 that such people, who are better informed will be judged more strictly.

Answer (score 0):

Most prophets are human.  (Let's not overlook that one was a donkey.)  Prophets are spokespersons for God--that does not mean they are perfect like God.  The Bible informs us that "all have sinned and come short of the glory of God" (Romans 3:23), which provides no exclusion for prophets.

Among the prophets whose sins are more darkly portrayed in the Bible we might remember Balaam, who was afterward slain for his unfaithfulness and avarice; Jonah, who initially ran away to avoid doing what God had asked; and the unnamed prophet who stopped to eat on his return from his prophetic mission, in direct contradiction to what God had told him--for which he was slain by a lion before reaching home (read the story in 1 Kings 13).  Abraham was also counted a prophet (the first to be called one in the Bible, and by God Himself--see Genesis 20:7) and is on record as having lied about his wife on more than one occasion--an example followed later by his son Isaac (see Genesis 12:11-13 and Genesis 20:2).

### Conclusion

Yes, prophets sometimes sin.